# Rename the [typo3-neos] tag to [neoscms]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I am a developer for the Neos project for which questions are tagged with [typo3-neos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3-neos) currently. As we split up from TYPO3 the naming changes and so I would like the tag to be renamed to [neoscms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neoscms) from now.

Currently [neoscms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neoscms) is still totally unused (at least my search didn't show anything).

Could that be done and/or what can I do to help it? The problem on my side is that neither I nor the other Neos developers have enough reputation to create a new tag. So someone else would have to do that.

Should we submit edit suggestions as recommended in the comments, or is there a better way?

Comment: Right now there are [91 questions tagged `[typo3-neos]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3-neos), which represent a significant amount of reading and evaluating so we don't botch the whole thing. Are you confident your dev team can take some time out not only to retag, but also to edit the questions so they become representative of the quality we all crave here?

Comment: I am quite confident that we can do that, but as you see I am not a very experienced stackoverflow user and would love to have some pointers to guidelines or things to look out for in those questions to maintain quality.

Comment: [The help center article on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is applicable to edits I believe, and contains some nice pointers.

Comment: Ok, just for reference, what is happening now? Do I need to do something or just wait?

Comment: This question will probably have a hard time gathering more views. At this juncture, I would suggest you select a couple of representative `[typo3-neos]` questions, retag and edit them into shape, then edit this meta-question with links to those questions, asking for validation that you're on the right track. That will result both in bumping this question back to the front page and in demonstrating to further readers/helpers you took the high road in this matter.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I don't even have enough reputation to create a new tag. So someone else would have to do that. And as far as I am aware I am the highest reputation developer of neos on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Ah, that's new information. You should add it to your question :) I would personally go through suggested edits, then, but others might offer better solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prepare some things in this regard:

**typo3-flow to flow-framework**

I created the tag flow-framework and changed good quality questions to the new tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow-framework

**typo3-neos to neoscms**

Same here, I created the tag and retagged some questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neoscms

If Frédéric could check if this work is going into the right direction, I would continue editing stuff.

**Update 31-03-2016**

For the past months, I retagged new questions and also existing questions to use only the new tags. However, there are still 100 (Flow) and 75 (Neos) questions with old tags. I dind't re-tag all because some of them are not really high-quality questions and answers but more installation support or questions that related to a bug in a dev release etc..

What's best to do: Re-tag all questions, no matter what value or quality they have?

Comment: @frédéric-hamidi I'd be greateful for your feedback on the update.